# tabsHideOnSubPages:false not working when a new page is pushed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple tabs applications with 3 tabs configured in a page called Dashboard. Switching between the tabs works well and other pages load up inside the tabbed stack. All Good.

Now I am attempting to dynamically push and bring into focus a new page when a button in the header is clicked. I have the tabsHideOnSubPages:false configured in app.module.ts but it doesn't seem to work. The page loads without the tabs and I see a Back arrow in the header.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Seems like I need to push into the tabbed stack and reference the correct tab index but I don't know how to do it.

Dashboard.ts

```
export class Dashboard {
  tab1root = Page1;
  tab2root = Page2;
  tab3root = Page3;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private menu:MenuController) {
/*Ignore this. Some old code when I was trying to add multiple sidemenus to the page. Don't have the menuToggle on the page template anymore  */  
this.menu.enable(false,"menu1");  
    this.menu.enable(false,"menu2");
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Dashboard');
  }
  profileClicked(event){
    this.navCtrl.push(Profile);
  }
}
```

Dashboard.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1root" tabTitle="Page1" tabIcon="color-wand" color=primary></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2root" tabTitle="Page2" tabIcon="star" tabBadge="3" color=primary></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3root" tabTitle="Page3" tabIcon="logo-usd" color=primary></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-title>
      <img class="titleLogo" src="/assets/img/titleicon.png"/>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons left>
     <button ion-button icon-only (click)="profileClicked($event)">
        <ion-icon name="person" color=primary></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons right>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon  name="md-happy" style="font-size:24px" color=primary></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      backButtonText: '',
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
      tabsHideOnSubPages:false
    }),

  ],
```